# repair IuganaTex Formulas

Tags: powerpoint, iguanatex

I had not installed ghostscript and ImageMagic probably but still could produce Latex equations with IguanaTex. Afterwards, I was not able to edit them, i got an error. Now i have installed everything and in a new Powerpoint I can edit. Is there a way to repair the old Powerpoint that was created under bad circumstances?

Comment: A `.pptx` file is a compressed XML file, you could try to open the `.pptx` with for example 7-Zip and look inside to see of any of your original equations are still there.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What do you mean with new and old powerpoint?